# Adding clock-time at bottom left of every page

Tags: datetime

How can I add a time-stamp of the time of compilation of the latex document (day, *and* clock-time in the form of HH:MM:SS) at the bottom left corner of every page, below the contents of the document?

Comment: Happy New year, hope you missed to keep the LaTeX tags what you tried, can you post a MWE of your document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newdateformat{myday}{%
\twodigit{\THEDAY}}
\settimeformat{hhmmsstime}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
     \AtTextLowerLeft{%
         \put(290,-20){\myday\today--\currenttime}%
     }%
}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]